# How to create or deploy another service/module (have deployed on default) on GAE [Google App engine] PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, service

I have already deployed on Google App Engine default service in PHP, but I need to create another service to enable me redirect to the mobile version of my website from example.com to mobile.example.com.

I read on google docs that you use I AM ADMIN, I have done the suggested method but to no avail.

Please kindly point me to the way. Thanks in advance.

[image: how to add another service.]

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. The solution was in the app.yaml file, add the service:service_name in the app.yaml if it is not created, it would create it automatically.

```
runtime: php72
runtime_config:
  document_root:

handlers:
  - url: /.*
     script: auto
     secure: always
     redirect_http_response_code: 301

  entrypoint:
     serve worker.php
```

TO

```
runtime: php72
runtime_config:
  document_root:

handlers:
  - url: /.*
     script: auto
     secure: always
     redirect_http_response_code: 301

  entrypoint:
     serve worker.php 

  service: mobile-frontend
```